# Mypy exclude the tests directory

Tags: python, mypy

I have the structure:

```
src/
tests/
tests/__init__.py
mypy.ini
```

In my mypy config I have:

```
[mypy-tests.*]
ignore_errors = True
```

but it is still returning lots of errors within the tests directory - less errors but still errors when running in the root:
`$ mypy .`

I know this config works:

```
[mypy]
exclude = tests
```

but I would like to not use this.

Comment: According to [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubgen.html#cmdoption-stubgen-ignore-errors) `ignore_errors` does not do what you expect it to do. Why don't you want to use `exclude = tests` ?

Comment: Well I was planning on slowly unexcluding the tests! Never mind will just use exclude!  Cheers